csv file reader, batch java spring
I am looking to read a csv file and convert the data into a Tarification object. At execution I get a parsing error. I do not understand why.
I have already tried removing quotes, changing delimiters, testing with other data, checking the field names.
Here is my Tarification object:
public class Tarification {

   private String id;

   private String age;

   private Double tauxApplicable;

   private String typeReseau;

   public Tarification(String id, String age, Double tauxApplicable, String typeReseau) {
       this.id = id;
       this.age = age;
       this.tauxApplicable = tauxApplicable;
       this.typeReseau = typeReseau;
   }
}

Here are the first lines of my csv file :
"816473dd-a200-4d05-9b5f-b77e7acd0bcf;50;5.1686956;01"
"f8fa6cbd-6bc9-4531-973f-cb6d1b10ae38;51;5.30325005;01"
"2a44e8f0-4eef-471c-a36a-cd5451e0bf91;52;5.44481506;01"
"02f26874-b585-41d6-b853-c9a6bb30c7e3;53;5.59391256;01"

Here is my reader :
public FlatFileItemReader<Tarification> reader(String filePath) throws IOException {
    LOGGER.info("----- Nouveau FlatFileItemReader avec input {} -----", filePath);

    // Tentative de résolution du fichier d'entrée sur Filesystem et sur Classpath par facilité
    Resource inputResource;
    if(new FileSystemResource(filePath).exists()) {
        inputResource = new FileSystemResource(filePath);
    } else {
        // Utile pour les TU
        inputResource = new ClassPathResource(filePath);
    }

    // Controle de disponibilité du fichier, son absence lèvera une exception en runtime
    if(!inputResource.exists()) {
        throw new IOException("Fichier non trouvé avec " + filePath);
    }

    BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<Tarification> beanWrapperFieldSetMapper = new BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<>();
    beanWrapperFieldSetMapper.setTargetType(Tarification.class);

    return new FlatFileItemReaderBuilder<Tarification>()
            .name("tarificationItemReader")
            .resource(inputResource)
            .delimited()
            .delimiter(";")
            .names("id", "age", "tauxApplicable", "typeReseau")
            .fieldSetMapper(beanWrapperFieldSetMapper)
            .build();
}

Here is the error :
org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileParseException: Parsing error at line: 1 in resource=[class path resource [mmaserenite_donnees_tarif_agenceMMACAP.csv]], input=[816473dd-a200-4d05-9b5f-b77e7acd0bcf;50;5.1686956;01]

